# hive.cli.print.current.db in hive-site.xml stopped working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I used to set hive.cli.print.current.db to true in $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml so that the database name is visible automatically in the hive prompt. This configuration recently stopped working, so I have to manually set its value every time I start hive. Has anyone encountered the same problem and what's your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have cluster management software that might have overwritten the file?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is the zookeeper. Does it overwrite the settings in hive-site.xml? Thanks!

Comment: Zookeeper wouldn't change your Hive settings.  I'm thinking more along the lines of Cloudera manager or Ambari.

Comment: No, I don't have Cloudera manager or Ambari installed. BTW, I am using the original Apache Hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property should be specified in .hiverc file(not in hive-site.xml)  in hive configuration directory(/etc/hive/conf). Create the file `<HIVE_CONF_DIR>/.hiverc` if it is not there with the following contents

```
set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
```

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. Thanks! I am wondering why setting this variable in hive-site.xml used to work in the past but not anymore, although I used the same Hive release.